# Closed Form Solution for a Sum of Linear Least Squares Problems of the Same Argument

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I have the following minimization problem of:

$$ \min_W \sum_{n=1}^{N} \| l_n - P_n W x_n \|^2_2$$

where $l_n$ is a $C$ dimensional vector, $P_n$ is a $C \times L$ dimensional matrix, $W$ is a $L \times D$ dimensional matrix and $x_n$ is a $D$ dimensional vector. We also know that $D > C  > L$ specifically. This is a convex problem and encouraged by its similarity with ordinary least squares $||b-Ax||_2^2$, I first tried to find a closed solution for it, without opting for numerical approaches. I take the derivative with respect to $W$ and find:

$$\dfrac{d}{dW}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \| l_n - P_nWx_n \|^2_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{N}-2P_n^T(l_n - P_nWx_n)x_n^T$$

But after this point, setting the derivative to zero and solving for the matrix $W$ doesn't seem to be doable to me. I just wanted to be sure and ask if we can solve the expression 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}-2P_n^T(l_n - P_nWx_n)x_n^T = 0$$ for $W$ analytically, without making use of tools of numerical optimization.

Comment: Have you tried using vectorization?

Comment: By $\| X \|_{2}$, do you mean the spectral norm or the Frobenius norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did 95% of the work.
I will write the problem as:

$$ \hat{W} = \arg \min_{W} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A W x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

This is a Convex smooth problem. Hence:

$$\begin{align*}
\hat{W} = \arg \min_{W} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A W x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} & \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \hat{W} x - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} }{\partial \hat{W}} = 0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow {A}^{T} \left( A \hat{W} x - y \right) {x}^{T} = 0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow {A}^{T} A \hat{W} x {x}^{T} = {A}^{T} y {x}^{T} \\
& \Leftrightarrow \hat{W} = {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} \left( {A}^{T} y {x}^{T} \right) {\left( x {x}^{T} \right)}^{-1} \\
\end{align*}$$

By the way, you could set $ z = \hat{W} x $ and then solve classic linear least squares for $ z $ yielding $ \hat{z} $. Then use:

$$ \hat{W} = \hat{z} {X}^{T} {\left( x {x}^{T} \right)}^{-1} $$

### Dealing with the Sum Form

On my above solution I missed the Sum of the data. So let's take care of that.

Since the Derivative is linear we need to find a solution to:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{N} {A}^{T}_{n} {A}_{n} \hat{W} {x}_{n} {x}^{T}_{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} {A}^{T}_{n} {y}_{n} {x}^{T}_{n} $$

We can rewrite this in the form:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{N} {B}_{n} \hat{W} {C}_{n} = D $$

Using the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) one could see that:

$$ B \hat{W} C = D \Rightarrow \operatorname{Vec} \left( B \hat{W} C \right) = \operatorname{Vec} \left( D \right) \Rightarrow \left( {B}^{T} \otimes C \right) \operatorname{Vec} \left( \hat{W} \right) = \operatorname{Vec} \left( D \right) $$

So the above becomes:

$$ \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \left( {B}^{T}_{n} \otimes {C}_{n} \right) \right) \operatorname{Vec} \left( \hat{W} \right) = \operatorname{Vec} \left( D \right) $$

Which can be written as a linear system.

Comment: What do you mean by $(xx^T)^{-1}$? Is it inverse to a *rank-one* matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But doesn't the summation over $N$ $x_n$ would create a problem here? In the actual case, I have: $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n^T(A_n \hat{W} x_n - y_n)x_n^T=0$$

Comment: Cont. from the last comment: Then we have: $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n^T A_n \hat{W} x_n x_n^T = \sum_{n=1}^{N} A_n^T y_n x_n^T$$ While the right side of the equation sums up to a nice vector, the left side stays problematic, as you can't isolate $\hat{W}$ in a single expression. Isn't this true?

Comment: @A.Γ., Since this is a least squares problem, all inverse operations are the Pseudo Inverse.

Comment: @UfukCanBicici You can isolate $W$ using the vectorization and the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations). Then $\text{vec}(W)$ will stand to the right in each term and can be factored out.

Comment: @Royi $(xx^T)$ is a rank 1 matrix, how could we have a matrix $A$ s.t. $(xx^T)A = I$ ? How would pseudo inverse help there?

Comment: @A.Γ., I will ask it differently. What's the solution for $ \arg \min_x {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ for $ A $ being rank 1 matrix? It will be the pseudo inverse given by the SVD. So in my solution above I'm using this interpretation of the inverse.

Comment: Just to give the Pseudo Inverse a formal structure - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760382.

Comment: @UfukCanBicici, I updated the answer with the case of the sum. Now it is fully solved. By the way it creates much larger matrices. For large matrices it might be faster to use the iterative approach.

Comment: @Royi Thank you again for the clarification. About the vectorization trick; can we say this is true: $$ \sum_n A_nXB_n = D \to (\sum_n (A_n^T \otimes B_n)) Vec(X) = Vec(D)$$. I wasn't able see a quick generalization of the trick to the matrix sums.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think this is clear: $$Vec(\sum_n A_nXB_n) = \sum_n Vec(A_n XB_n) = \sum_n (A_n^T \otimes B_n)Vec(X)$$.

Comment: @UfukCanBicici, Yes. I was sloppy there. I fixed it. Now it is complete :-).