# The pseudoinverse of a rank one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with real coefficients. It is proved, for example here [Derive the Pseudo Inverse (Moore Penrose) of Rank 1 Matrix as a Scalar Multiple of Its Transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760382/derive-the-pseudo-inverse-moore-penrose-of-rank-1-matrix-as-a-scalar-multiple) that if $A$ is a rank one matrix, then the pseudoinverse $A^+$ is $\frac{1}{c}A^*$, where $c$ is the sum of the squares of the entries of $A$. Is the converse true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. $A A^+$ is the orthogonal projection on the range $\text{Ran}(A)$.  Its trace is the rank of $A$.  But
 $\text{tr}(A A^*)$ is the sum of the squares of the entries of $A$. Thus if your condition holds, 
$$\text{rank}(A) =\text{tr}(A A^+)= \text{tr}(A A^*/c) = c/c = 1$$